# Conditional AND OR two different values

Tags: xslt, conditional-statements

I have a concatenation of AND and OR for 2 different variables. And I tried the following:

```
<xsl:if test="$countryCode = '104'
               and 
              (transactionType != 'Allowance'
                or 
               revenueCenter != '1100')">
```

But that does not work. Is it possible to do a conditional test or do I have to split it up like this:

```
<xsl:if test="$countryCode='104'>
```

and in a second element I do:

```
<xsl:if transactionType!='Allowance' or revenueCenter!='1100'>
```

Comment: What is transactionType and revenueCenter? There might be a problem with the variable reference (why not use $?) The second approach is wrong

Comment: How is it "not working"? Are you getting any results; if so, how do they differ from what you expect?

Comment: Hello Zoltan, the references are okay. I did check them by outputting them in a <test> element. A certain XML element is supposed to be created if the countryCode matches 104 and one of the other conditions is true (no "Allowance" and no "1100" in the respective references). I am trying around with the function "Contains". Maybe I get the wanted output.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and proposed safer refactoring.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The XPath expression**:

```
    $countryCode='104' 
   and  
    (transactionType!='Allowance' or revenueCenter!='1100')
```

**is syntactically correct**.

We cannot say anything about the semantics, as no XML document is provided and there is no explanation what the expression must select.

**As usual, there is the recommendation not to ose the `!=` operator, unless really necessary** -- its use when one of the arguments is a node-set (or sequence or node-set in XPath 2.0) is very far from what most people expect.

Instead of `!=` better use the function `not()`:

```
  $countryCode='104' 
 and  
  (not(transactionType='Allowance') or not(revenueCenter='1100'))
```

and this can further be refactored to the shorter and equivalent:

```
  $countryCode='104' 
 and  
  not(transactionType='Allowance' and revenueCenter='1100')
```

Comment: Hello Dimitre, Thank you very much for this answer. I did not know of the problem with the operator "!=". I have been using it a lot but will try to use "not()" in the future. I tried with your last example code and it works perfectly - thank you!

Comment: The main difference is that if there is no transactionType, `transactionType != 'Allowance'` returns false, while `not(transactionType = 'Allowance')` returns true. In future please provide some source XML so that it is easier to help you.

Comment: @Peter: You are welcome. I couldn't reply immediately as I was busy reading the XML Prague article by @Michael-Kay on implementing XSLT 2.0 in the browser -- great stuff!!!